# MySQL: Find duplicates across three tables for lat lng that are within X feet of one another

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have three tables (t1, t2, t3) all of which contain id, lat, lng.
There are possible duplicate entries that I want to identify and possibly eliminate (if they are truly duplicates).  The issue is that the lat and lng might not be EXACT matches, so the typical count(*) >1 method of finding duplicates will not work since I want to allow for a slight geolocation variance (say 250 feet or about 0.005 degrees in each lat and lng) in any given direction.

I found a similar question here, but it doesn't identify this exact issue and I wasn't able to extrapolate that code for my answer:
[All Lat Lng of a sql table within 15 Km to each Lat lng of a different table-sql 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834277/all-lat-lng-of-a-sql-table-within-15-km-to-each-lat-lng-of-a-different-table-sql)

I did find some code that works to identify EXACT duplicate lat/lng but it doesn't tell me which tables the duplicates are in so I can manually research them or to allow for even the slightest deviation in lat/lng and only returns one id, lat, lng, and count for each duplicate.

There could be "duplicates" that have lat's of 32.333 and 32.336 but the code below will not account for them, as it will see them as unique.

```
`SELECT id, lat, lng, COUNT( * ) 
    FROM (
        SELECT id, lat, lng
        FROM t1
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT id, lat, lng
        FROM t2
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT id, lat, lng
        FROM t3
    ) tbl
GROUP BY lat, lng
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
ORDER BY lat;`
```

Ideally, the output should look something like this:

```
`t1.id  t2.id   t3.id
432     1087        <-- found 2 rows within 250 of each other in t1 & t2
12      832         <-- found 2 rows within 250 of each other in t1 & t3
88      654      789<-- found 3 rows within 250 of each other in t1,t2&t3`

An example of "close duplicates" would be:
32.332, -87.556
32.336, -87.560
```

Comment: Could you work it out youself if you know how to [find distance between two points using latitude and longitude in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370975/find-distance-between-two-points-using-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql)?

Comment: I think that is a step in the right direction, and it would be easy if I was trying to compare them to a known location.  But I want to compare them to each other.  **Similar** to a "count(*)>1" method of finding exact duplicates. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: [This is along the same lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834277/all-lat-lng-of-a-sql-table-within-15-km-to-each-lat-lng-of-a-different-table-sql?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: By adding a constant to the union all statements I am able to at least identify the table for each row:
`SELECT id, lat, lng, COUNT( * ) 
FROM (
SELECT  't1' AS table_name, id, lat, lng
FROM  t1
UNION ALL SELECT  't2' AS table_name, id, lat, lng
FROM  t2
UNION ALL SELECT  't3' AS table_name, id, lat, lng
FROM  t3
)tbl
GROUP BY lat, lng
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
ORDER BY  id`